# Weird Joomla JRoute() behavior

Tags: joomla, joomla-component

Why does JRoute include parts that weren't set in the output SEF Url ?

Example:
I have a view that lists Items, every item links to another view (Item) with an ID. When I put all parts of the query string together I get both views on the URL:

domain.com/index.php/component/ **items**/ **item**/1-alias

instead of

domain.com/index.php/component/**item**/1-alias

because I use different views for all the parts of the component and not layouts.

Both URLs work just fine, but why does it do that? I don't want it to build the SEF URL with the original view of Items, just the view for single items. It wouldn't be a problem if the Item view wasn't getting the menu param of the Items view.

Edit:

This is how I use the JRoute::_() method.

```
JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_componentname&view=show&show_id='.$item->slug);
```

And the contents of the router.php script

```
jimport('joomla.database.databasequery');

function ComponentnameBuildRoute(&$query) {

    $segments = array();

    if(isset($query['view'])) {
        $view = $query['view'];
        $segments[] = $view;
        unset($query['view']);
    }

    if(isset($query['task'])) {
        $view = $query['task'];
        $segments[] = $view;
        unset($query['task']);
    }

    if(isset($query['show_id'])) {
        $view = $query['show_id'];
        $segments[] = $view;
        unset($query['show_id']);
    }

    if(isset($query['genre_id'])) {
        $view = $query['genre_id'];
        $segments[] = $view;
        unset($query['genre_id']);
    }

    if(isset($query['rated_id'])) {
        $view = $query['rated_id'];
        $segments[] = $view;
        unset($query['rated_id']);
    }

    return $segments;
}

function ComponentnameParseRoute($segments) {

    $vars = array();

    switch($segments[0]) {

        case 'show':
            $vars['view'] = $segments[0];
            $id = explode('-', $segments[1]);
            $vars['show_id'] = (int)$id[0];
            break;
        case 'genre':
            $vars['view'] = $segments[0];
            $vars['genre_id'] = (int)$segments[1];
            break;
        case 'rating':
            $vars['view'] = $segments[0];
            $vars['rated_id'] = (int)$segments[1];
            break;
        case 'shows':
            $vars['view'] = $segments[0];
            break;
        case 'genres':
            $vars['view'] = $segments[0];
            break;
        case 'ratings':
            $vars['view'] = $segments[0];
            break;
    }

    return($vars);
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code you use for JRoute::_()?

Comment: I've edited the original post with the code you asked.

Comment: Ofcourse the example URL uses Items and Item as view but the real URL is Shows/Show

Comment: So if you echo JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_componentname&view=show&show_id='.$item->slug); does it show the shows/show URL or is that added after you click it?

Comment: It takes the alias of the Menu Item and adds it before the view part. So the first element is the menu alias and then the view of the item. How can I prevent that?